# How to check if mongodb docker container is up

Tags: mongodb, docker

The mongodb docker container takes few seconds to receive connections on the specified port. I would like to know how we can check if that port is up before continuing.

Comment: Use Dockerfile HEALTHCHECK. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38300925/193016

Answer (score 3):

If mongodb is configured to accepted connection on `localhost:27017` then run the following command:

```
TIMEOUT=30; until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --fail localhost:27017); do printf '.'; sleep 1; if [[ $var -eq ${TIMEOUT} ]] ; then exit 1; fi; var=$((var+1)); done
```