# Docker-Compose: how to wait for other service to be ready?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wait

I have the following **docker-compose**, where I need to wait for the service **jhipster-registry** to be up and accepting connections before starting **myprogram-app**.

I tried the healtcheck way, following the official doc https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/

```
version: '2.1'
services:
    myprogram-app:
        image: myprogram
        mem_limit: 1024m
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
            - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/config
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://myprogram-postgresql:5432/myprogram
            - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=0
            - SPRING_DATA_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER_NODES=myprogram-elasticsearch:9300
            - JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=53bqDrurQAthqrXG
            - EMAIL_USERNAME
            - EMAIL_PASSWORD
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        networks:
          - backend
        depends_on:
          - jhipster-registry:
              "condition": service_started
          - myprogram-postgresql
          - myprogram-elasticsearch
    myprogram-postgresql:
        image: postgres:9.6.5
        mem_limit: 256m
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=myprogram
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myprogram
        networks:
          - backend
    myprogram-elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:2.4.6
        mem_limit: 512m
        networks:
          - backend
    jhipster-registry:
        extends:
            file: jhipster-registry.yml
            service: jhipster-registry
        mem_limit: 512m
        ports:
            - 8761:8761
        networks:
          - backend
        healthcheck:
          test: "exit 0"
networks:
  backend:
    driver: "bridge"
```

but I get the following error when running `docker-compose up`:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.myprogram-app.depends_on contains {"jhipster-registry": {"condition": "service_started"}}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string
```

Am I doing something wrong, or this feature is no more supported? How to achieve this sync between services?

**Updated version**

```
version: '2.1'
services:
    myprogram-app:
        image: myprogram
        mem_limit: 1024m
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
            - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/config
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://myprogram-postgresql:5432/myprogram
            - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=0
            - SPRING_DATA_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER_NODES=myprogram-elasticsearch:9300
            - JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=53bqDrurQAthqrXG
            - EMAIL_USERNAME
            - EMAIL_PASSWORD
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        networks:
          - backend
        depends_on:
          jhipster-registry:
            condition: service_healthy
          myprogram-postgresql:
            condition: service_started
          myprogram-elasticsearch:
            condition: service_started
        #restart: on-failure
    myprogram-postgresql:
        image: postgres:9.6.5
        mem_limit: 256m
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=myprogram
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=tuenemreh
        networks:
          - backend
    myprogram-elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:2.4.6
        mem_limit: 512m
        networks:
          - backend
    jhipster-registry:
        extends:
            file: jhipster-registry.yml
            service: jhipster-registry
        mem_limit: 512m
        ports:
            - 8761:8761
        networks:
          - backend
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://jhipster-registry:8761", "|| exit 1"]
          interval: 30s
          retries: 20
          #start_period: 30s
networks:
  backend:
    driver: "bridge"
```

The updated version gives me a different error,

```
ERROR: for myprogram-app  Container "8ebca614590c" is unhealthy.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

saying that the container of jhipster-registry is unhealthy, but it's reachable via browser. How can I fix the command in the healthcheck to make it work?

Comment: **See Also**: [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31746182/1366033)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on) suggests that, *in Docker Compose version 2 files specifically*, `depends_on:` can be a list of strings, or a mapping where the keys are service names and the values are conditions.  For the services where you don't have (or need) health checks, there is a `service_started` condition.

```yaml
depends_on:
  # notice: these lines don't start with "-"
  jhipster-registry:
    condition: service_healthy
  myprogram-postgresql:
    condition: service_started
  myprogram-elasticsearch:
    condition: service_started
```

Depending on how much control you have over your program and its libraries, it's better still if you can arrange for the service to be able to start without its dependencies necessarily being available (equivalently, to function if its dependencies die while the service is running), and not use the `depends_on:` option.  You might return an HTTP 503 Service Unavailable error if the database is down, for instance.  Another strategy that often is helpful is to immediately exit if your dependencies aren't available but use [a setting](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#restart) like `restart: on-error` to ask the orchestrator to restart the service.

Comment: Ok, the previous error now is gone. I updated the question with your fix, but the command used does not seem to work. How do I make curl return 0 (which I read it shoud, but it doesn't) if the jhipser-registry:8761 is up?

Comment: The [curl man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) has a pretty exhaustive list of exit codes; the [Docker HEALTHCHECK docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) suggest `curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1` as a typical health check (this requires your image have curl installed).

Comment: this answer is not relevant anymore. from the docs:
```Version 3 no longer supports the condition form of depends_on```

Comment: It is relevant again. From docker-compose 1.27.0 it supports the COMPOSE_SPEC standard for v3 which includes [`condition`](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#depends_on) for `depends_on`, see [release notes](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.27.0)

Answer (score 23):

#### Best Approach - Resilient App Starts

While docker *does* support startup dependencies, they officially recommend updating your app start logic to test for the availability of external dependencies and retry.  This has lots of benefits for robust applications that may restart in the wild on the fly in addition to circumventing the race condition in `docker compose up`

#### `depends_on` & `service_healthy` - Compose 1.27.0<sup>+</sup>

`depends_on` is back in docker compose v1.27.0+ (was deprecated in v3) in the [Compose Specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on)

Each service should also implement a `service_healthy` check to be able to report if it's fully setup and ready for downstream dependencies.

```yaml
version: '3.0'
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: tests/Docker/Dockerfile-PHP
    depends_on:
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy
  redis:
    image: redis
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 30
```

#### `wait-for-it.sh`

The recommended approach from docker according to their docs on [Control startup and shutdown order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) is to download [`wait-for-it.sh`](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh) which takes in the `domain:port` to poll and then executes the next set of commands if successful.

```yaml
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "app.py"]
  db:
    image: postgres
```

**Note**: This requires overriding the startup command of the image, so make sure you know what wanted to pass to maintain parity of the default startup.

#### Further Reading

- [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31746182/1366033)
- [Difference between links and depends_on in docker_compose.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35832095/1366033)
- [How can I wait for a docker container to be up and running?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21183088/1366033)
- [Docker Compose Wait til dependency container is fully up before launching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55502234/1366033)
- [depends_on doesn't wait for another service in docker-compose 1.22.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52699899/1366033)

Comment: `depends_on: ... condition: service_healthy` works again since "Compose 1.27.0+" (see [Compose specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file)). Just remove the (now deprecated) main `version` field.

Thanks to @Channy's [comment and reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52322800/docker-compose-how-to-wait-for-other-service-to-be-ready#comment129420778_61523995)

Comment: @Dominik - thanks, updated to bring up to date with current API

Answer (score 10):

**Update to version 3+.**

Please follow the [documents](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on)  from version 3:

> There are several things to be aware of when using `depends_on`:
>
> `depends_on` does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before
>   starting web - only until they have been started. 
> If you need to wait
>   for a service to be ready, see Controlling startup order for more on
>   this problem and strategies for solving it. 
> **Version 3 no longer
>   supports the condition form of `depends_on`.** 
>   The `depends_on` option is
>   ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a version 3 Compose
>   file.

I would consider using the [restart_policy](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart_policy) option for configuring your *myprogram-app* to restart until the *jhipster-registry* is up and accepting connections:

```
 restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 3s
        max_attempts: 5
        window: 60s
```

Comment: as many have pointed out above, it seems that they _do_ support this in the specification: https://github.com/peter-evans/docker-compose-healthcheck/issues/3#issuecomment-790332404

Answer (score 7):

With the new docker compose API, we can now use the new `--wait` option:

```
docker compose up --wait
```

If your service has a healthcheck, Docker waits until it has the "healthy" status; otherwise, it waits for the service to be started. That's why it is crucial to have relevant healthchecks for all your services.

Note that this option automatically activates the `--detach` option.

Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/#options).

Comment: there is no such flag as `--wait`, any link to the docs?

Comment: Doc link added. :)

Answer (score 2):

The best approach I found is to check for the desired port in the entrypoint. There are different ways to do that e.g. [`wait-for-it`](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) but I like to use this solution that is cross-platform between apline and bash images and doesn't download custom scripts from GitHub:

Install `netcat-openbsd` (works with `apt` and `apk`). Then in the entrypoint (works with both `#!/bin/bash` and `#!/bin/sh`):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

wait_for()
{
  echo "Waiting $1 seconds for $2:$3"
  timeout $1 sh -c 'until nc -z $0 $1; do sleep 0.1; done' $2 $3 || return 1
  echo "$2:$3 available"
}


wait_for 10 db 5432
wait_for 10 redis 6379
```

You can also make this into a 1-liner if you don't want to print anything.

Answer (score 1):

Although you already got an answer, it should be mentioned that what you are trying to achieve have some nasty risks.

Ideally a service should be self sufficient and smart enough to retry and await for dependencies to be available (before a going down). Otherwise you will be more exposed to one failure propagating to other services. Also consider that a system reboot, unlike a manual start might ignore the dependencies order.

If one service crash causes all your system to go down, you might have a tool to restart everything again, but it would be better having services that resist that case.

Answer (score 1):

After trying several approaches, IMO the simplest and most elegant option is using the `jwilder/dockerize` ([dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize)) utility image with its `-wait` flag. Here is a simple example where I need a PostgreSQL database to be ready before starting my app:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  # Start Postgres.
  db:
    image: postgres

  # Wait for Postgres to be joinable.
  check-db-started: 
    image: jwilder/dockerize:0.6.1
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: 'dockerize -wait=tcp://db:5432'
  
  # Only start myapp once Postgres is joinable.
  myapp:
    image: myapp:latest
    depends_on:
      - check-db-started
```

Comment: Not sure how this works for you - as it was pointed out in other answers, `depends_on` doesn't wait for the command to complete...

Comment: Erm, yes I think it does. What it doesn't do is _wait for the DB to be ready to serve connections_, which is a different thing.

Comment: This confirmed works. I have been scratching my head on this problem for a few hours, until I see this elegant solution.