# docker-compose, NodeJS starts before MYSQL even when using depends_on

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

This only occurs whenever building the project [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/midrizi/bookstore_api/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) but for some reason, docker doesn't wait for the port to become active and then execute the next service.

My question is: if there is any way to do this without using `wait-for-it` or programs similar to it

docker-compose logs:

[image]

**Edit:** I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) which was unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe this can help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699899/depends-on-doesnt-wait-for-another-service-in-docker-compose-1-22-0

Comment: it already has restart always, also tried your suggestion it doesn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

`depends_on` means only that it will wait when container starts but it does not mean that service inside that container is ready.
Look here how you have to wait for db is ready https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/blob/master/api/docker/php/docker-entrypoint.sh#L29