# How to wait until dependent services like elasticsearch are available for my service in docker-compose

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

How to wait until dependent services are available in docker-compose

Elasticsearch runs on a different machine and if my application is started via docker-compose it fails to start. But how do I wait, until the elasticsearch instance is available and running on a different machine so that the application can start

Comment: Add `restart: always` to your application.

Answer (score 1):

one option could be to use [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it)

> wait-for-it.sh is a pure bash script that will wait on the availability of a host and TCP port. It is useful for synchronizing the spin-up of interdependent services, such as linked docker containers. Since it is a pure bash script, it does not have any external dependencies.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52322800/docker-compose-how-to-wait-for-other-service-to-be-ready) is another SO that asks the same question.