# How can I wait for the container to be healthy in GitHub action?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am using GitHub action to do some automation test and my application was developed in docker.

```
name: Docker Image CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master]

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker-compose build

    - name: up mysql and apache container runs
      run: docker-compose up -d 

    - name: install dependencies
      run: docker exec  myapp php composer.phar install
  
    - name: show running container
      run: docker ps 


    - name: run unit test
      run: docker exec  myapp ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

At the step 'show running container', I can see that all the containers are running but for the MySQL, the status is (health: starting). Thus, my unit test cases all failed as it requires a connection to MySQL. So may I know if there is a way to start the unit case only when the MySQL container's status is healthy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to offer a solution, not a smart one but it requires minimum configuration and ready to go, just use the GitHub Action for Sleeping.

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Sleep for 30 seconds
      uses: jakejarvis/wait-action@master
      with:
        time: '30s'
```

Assumption: your Mysql server will be up and running in 30s.

Comment: Isn't it overkill to use an action for that since you can just use `run: sleep 30`

Answer (score 7):

You can wait for all services to be healthy by using the `--wait` option, documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/#options).

Example command: `docker compose up --detach --wait --wait-timeout 30`

The command will return only after all services are running, or if a healthcheck is defined are healthy.

Comment: This is the real answer

Comment: Using GH's runner for Ubuntu 22.x and 20.x, I was having an issue where `docker-compose up --wait` was not working. The `--wait` flag is not supported.

To save those who find themselves in this same SO answer, @skowalak is spot on by using `docker compose up .. --wait`. The docker-compose cli on the GH runners is a bit old it seems and doesn't have this flag whereas the docker cli does.

Answer (score 3):

My approach was to use:

1. in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
healthcheck:
  test: curl --fail http://localhost/ping || exit 1
  interval: 2s
  retries: 10
  start_period: 10s
  timeout: 10s
```

2. in my Github Actions workflow:

```
- name: Wait for healthchecks
  run: timeout 60s sh -c 'until docker ps | grep <CONTAINER_NAME> | grep -q healthy; do echo "Waiting for container to be healthy..."; sleep 2; done'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *thegabriele97/dockercompose-health-action*

```yaml
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Check services healthiness
        uses: thegabriele97/dockercompose-health-action@main
        with:
          timeout: '60'
          workdir: 'src'
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) states:

> To handle this, design your application to attempt to re-establish a connection to the database after a failure. If the application retries the connection, it can eventually connect to the database.

If you can't implement this at the moment, you can write some simple script that will indefinitely try a simple statement on the database. Once the script succeed you exit loop and start your unit tests. Check the documentation link I've provided, you'll find there an example of such script (`wait-for-it.sh`).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in documentation:

On Linux and macOS runners, use the sleep command:

```yaml
- name: Sleep for 30 seconds
  run: sleep 30s
  shell: bash
```

On Windows runners, use the Start-Sleep command:

```yaml
- name: Sleep for 30 seconds
  run: Start-Sleep -s 30
  shell: powershell
```