# How to make Terraform wait till the docker image with spring boot application is started?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, terraform

I'm creating DB using terraform. After DB is created Im running docker image with local provisioner. The image is spring boot application which will connect to the created DB and will create DB schema. This takes like 3 minutes to complete and I need after that run another command which will connect to the DB using Sqlcmd and create new user in the new schema.

But terraform doesn't wait for the docker image to start the spring boot app and just continue with execution so the next command will fail because DB doesn't exists yet.

Is there a way how to do this?

Create DB TF:

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "test-db" {
  name      = var.azurerm_mssql_test_database_name
  server_id = azurerm_mssql_server.test-server.id
  sku_name  = var.mssql_sku_name

    provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]  
    command = <<EOF
docker run --env-file env.list -d -it -p 8080:8000 --name=init repo/spring-boot-app
sqlcmd -S tcp:some-server.database.windows.net -d ${var.azurerm_mssql_test_database_name} -U ${var.mssql_admin_username} -P ${var.mssql_admin_password} -i create-user.sql
    EOF
  } 

}
```

Comment: A couple of the approaches in [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) aren't actually Compose-specific, but just involve waiting until a client program like `sqlcmd` can run successfully.  Can you put a shell wait loop like this into the `provisioner` block?

Comment: Yes. a look after the docker run command should do it.  see some examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183088/how-can-i-wait-for-a-docker-container-to-be-up-and-running